# Problem with Using RcppMLPACK in My Own R Package

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, mlpack, rcppmlpack

I am trying to develop an `R` package using the `kmeans` functionality from `RcppMLPACK`.
I in including the header part below:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppMLPACK.h>
#include <RcppGSL.h>
#include <RcppDist.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<omp.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_sf.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppProgress)]]
#include <progress.hpp>
#include <progress_bar.hpp>


// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo,RcppDist)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppMLPACK)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

using namespace mlpack::kmeans ;
using namespace arma;
```

My `Makevars` file-body is given below:

```
CXX_STD = CXX17
GSL_CFLAGS=`${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript -e "RcppGSL:::CFlags()" 4`
GSL_LIBS=`${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript -e "RcppGSL:::LdFlags()"`
RCPP_LDFLAGS=`${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"`

PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(GSL_CFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) $(GSL_LIBS) $(RCPP_LDFLAGS)
```

I am using macOS ventura. When I try to build my `R` package, it shows the following error

```
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/RcppMLPACK/include/mlpack/core.hpp:171,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/RcppMLPACK/include/RcppMLPACK.h:4,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:6:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/RcppMLPACK/include/mlpack/prereqs.hpp:46:10: fatal error: boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp: No such file or directory
  >> 46 | #include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

However if I simply `Rcpp::sourcecpp` on my `C++` file, then it compiles perfectly. Kindly help me in debugging the issue.

P.S. I am using `gcc` instead of `clang`. Both `boost` and `mlpack` are installed in my system.

Comment: `RcppMLPACK` coauthor here:  you probably want the much newer, more complete, more featureful `mlpack` package instead, it also on CRAN where `RcppMLPACK` no longer is. See https://cran.r-project.org/package=mlpack.  Other than that your error is local: the installed Boost version is either not found, or too, or causes some other issue.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you very much for the prompt response. Can you please provide any documentation for linking the newer `mlpack` and using its functionalities in my own `R` package?

Comment: If you want just `kmeans` would it not be easier to just use the provided `Armadillo` function (see https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#kmeans) from `RcppArmadillo` ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Absolutely. However, in that function I do not see any option to obtain the cluster membership indicators. I only see that the cluster centroids will be stored in the `means` matrix as defined in the documentation.

Nevertheless it would be useful to know how to link `mlpack` in my `R` package as it is much more flexible.

Comment: You could try to help us heko you if you actually had _minimalle complete verifiable example_ (as described eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) in eg a minimal repo or gist. You probably can and should remove header includes for unrelated libraries such as the GSL, Armadillo (implied !!), RcppDist and so on. And IIRC current `mlpack` no longer requires Boost. _Minimal examples_ help, it may even help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic is a little underdocumented: `mlpack` is a large package and contains a lot, but there is no 'quick start' from R.  At the same time your question may have overcomplicated things by including several kitchen sinks worth of included libraries. I find that adding too much too early muddles things.

So here is what I did (usng mlpack 3.4.2, see below for mlpack 4.0.1):

##### Viability

I first created a *minimal* C++ file include just the two headers and not doing much.

It looked like this, give or take:

```
#include <Rcpp/Rcpp>
#include <mlpack.h>
    
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(mlpack)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void foo() {
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Foo\n";
}

/*** R
foo()
*/
```

Compiling this means that `mlpack` is found. I have the CRAN package installed.

##### Running kmeans (mlpack 3.4.*, see below for 4.0.1)

This gets *a little more complicated for me* as I happen to (mainly) work on Ubuntu 22.10 which only has an older `mlpack 3.4.2` as a convenient system library from the distribution.  I *think* that with a newer `mlpack` release 4.* I would not need to link.

As I often do I took a simple example from the unit tests. It has data, as well as an invocation.  The full file now is as follows:

```
#include <Rcpp/Rcpp>
#include <mlpack.h>

// Two include directories adjusted for my use of mlpack 3.4.2 on Ubuntu
#include <mlpack/core.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/kmeans.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/random_partition.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/neighbor_search/neighbor_search.hpp>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(mlpack)]]

// This is 'borrowed' from mlpack's own src/mlpack/tests/kmeans_test.cpp
// and src/mlpack/tests/kmeans_test.cpp. We borrow the data set, and the
// code from the first test function. Passing data from R in easy thanks
// to RcppArmadillo, 'and left as an exercise'.

// Generate dataset; written transposed because it's easier to read.
arma::mat kMeansData("  0.0   0.0;" // Class 1.
                     "  0.3   0.4;"
                     "  0.1   0.0;"
                     "  0.1   0.3;"
                     " -0.2  -0.2;"
                     " -0.1   0.3;"
                     " -0.4   0.1;"
                     "  0.2  -0.1;"
                     "  0.3   0.0;"
                     " -0.3  -0.3;"
                     "  0.1  -0.1;"
                     "  0.2  -0.3;"
                     " -0.3   0.2;"
                     " 10.0  10.0;" // Class 2.
                     " 10.1   9.9;"
                     "  9.9  10.0;"
                     " 10.2   9.7;"
                     " 10.2   9.8;"
                     "  9.7  10.3;"
                     "  9.9  10.1;"
                     "-10.0   5.0;" // Class 3.
                     " -9.8   5.1;"
                     " -9.9   4.9;"
                     "-10.0   4.9;"
                     "-10.2   5.2;"
                     "-10.1   5.1;"
                     "-10.3   5.3;"
                     "-10.0   4.8;"
                     " -9.6   5.0;"
                     " -9.8   5.1;");


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::Row<size_t> kmeansDemo() {

    mlpack::kmeans::KMeans<mlpack::metric::EuclideanDistance, 
                           mlpack::kmeans::RandomPartition> kmeans;

    arma::Row<size_t> assignments;
    kmeans.Cluster((arma::mat) trans(kMeansData), 3, assignments);

    return assignments;
}

/*** R
kmeansDemo()
*/
```

Now, *because I am on mlpack 3.4.2* I have to link so I also need to run `Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-lmlpack")` -- and I had to adjust the headers slightly from the example I took from the repo where it set up for mlpack 4.1.*.

The link step will vary depending on where you are running this.

But with that, my R session produces the result:

```
> Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-lmlpack")
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/76319284/answer.cpp")

> kmeansDemo()
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2     2     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
>
```

##### Running kmeans (mlpack 4.0.1)

Things are even better and easier with a (more) current version of `mlpack`.  After I installed 4.0.1 on Ubuntu, the header include simplifiied a little, the namespace changed a litte, I added an R package dependency on [RcppEnsmallen](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppEnsmallen) (which provides optimization routines).  Most importantly, I can build this without linking.

##### Updated Code (for mlpack 4.0.1)

```
#include <Rcpp/Rcpp>
#include <mlpack.h>

// Adjusted for mlpack 4.0.1
#include <mlpack/core.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/random_partition.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/neighbor_search/neighbor_search.hpp>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEnsmallen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(mlpack)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp14)]]

// This is 'borrowed' from mlpack's own src/mlpack/tests/kmeans_test.cpp
// and src/mlpack/tests/kmeans_test.cpp. We borrow the data set, and the
// code from the first test function. Passing data from R in easy thanks
// to RcppArmadillo, 'and left as an exercise'.

// Generate dataset; written transposed because it's easier to read.
arma::mat kMeansData("  0.0   0.0;" // Class 1.
                     "  0.3   0.4;"
                     "  0.1   0.0;"
                     "  0.1   0.3;"
                     " -0.2  -0.2;"
                     " -0.1   0.3;"
                     " -0.4   0.1;"
                     "  0.2  -0.1;"
                     "  0.3   0.0;"
                     " -0.3  -0.3;"
                     "  0.1  -0.1;"
                     "  0.2  -0.3;"
                     " -0.3   0.2;"
                     " 10.0  10.0;" // Class 2.
                     " 10.1   9.9;"
                     "  9.9  10.0;"
                     " 10.2   9.7;"
                     " 10.2   9.8;"
                     "  9.7  10.3;"
                     "  9.9  10.1;"
                     "-10.0   5.0;" // Class 3.
                     " -9.8   5.1;"
                     " -9.9   4.9;"
                     "-10.0   4.9;"
                     "-10.2   5.2;"
                     "-10.1   5.1;"
                     "-10.3   5.3;"
                     "-10.0   4.8;"
                     " -9.6   5.0;"
                     " -9.8   5.1;");


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::Row<size_t> kmeansDemo() {

    mlpack::KMeans<mlpack::EuclideanDistance, mlpack::RandomPartition> kmeans;

    arma::Row<size_t> assignments;
    kmeans.Cluster((arma::mat) trans(kMeansData), 3, assignments);

    return assignments;
}

/*** R
kmeansDemo()
*/
```

It of course builds and runs the same and now includes a small amount of default logging:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("answer.cpp")

> kmeansDemo()
[INFO ] KMeans::Cluster(): iteration 1, residual 14.8221.
[INFO ] KMeans::Cluster(): iteration 2, residual 1.77636e-15.
[INFO ] KMeans::Cluster(): converged after 2 iterations.
[INFO ] 186 distance calculations.
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2     2     2     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
>
```

Comment: I can `sourceCpp` the `cpp` script with the link `Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-lmlpack")`. But I am unsuccessful in creating an `R` package. In the `src` foler I have put only this `answer.cpp` file. `DESCRIPTION` file is

```
Package: mlpacktestnkc
Type: Package
Title: What the package does (short line)
Version: 1.0
Date: 2023-05-25
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: Who to complain to <yourfault@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: What license is it under?
Imports: Rcpp (>= 1.0.10)
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, mlpack
```

Comment: Continued: The `Makevars` file:
```
RCPP_LDFLAGS=`${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"`
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) $(RCPP_LDFLAGS) 
```

But the package does not build.

Comment: I believe I addressed your question here.  It seems to me you could upvote it if you think it serves you (click on the up-ward facing triangle) and/or possible accept it (click on the tick mark).  Comments here are not the place for extended followup.  You could ask a new question here, or come to the rcpp mailing list.  Switching to other means (private email) should be really be avoided as it does not scale: you will not get more eyeballs and help, and the provided answer cannot help anybody else.  I hope you understand.

Comment: In short, R packages work differently and we have written about that many, many times both here (search among the nearly 3000 questions for Rcpp), on the Rcpp mailing list, as well as many other places.  You now have a 'basic' packaging question ("how do I link to an external library") and I wrote an entire vignette (and arXiv paper) on that; the real problem is how to put the library onto other user's machines.

Comment: I understand. It would be really helpful if you can provide the link to your arxiv paper and the vignette for linking external `C++` libraries in my `R` package. Thanks!

Comment: The vignette is included in the Rcpp package, the arXiv paper is the same, available where you would expect it, and also linked from my website.

Comment: Part of the problem also is that the R package `mlpack` does not install the mlpack (project) headers.  I think it should, and [I opened an isssue](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3486).

Comment: May be. I have no issues in seamlessly using other packages like RcppDIST, splines2, etc. There are some issues regarding RcppGSL though; from your Rcpp book I was able to resolve it for macOS & Linux by adding cppflags and ldflags in the `Makevars` file but it does not work in Windows. Anyway, I really appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: You need to calmly think through the difference between a _header-only_ package like RcppArmadillo and one _that requires linking_ such as RcppGSL.  Not the same thing, and the reason the vignette runs over several pages.  Now, _current_ mlpack _should be_ in the RcppArmadillo case of header-only use.

Comment: I tried to replicate the new  solution you proposed for mlpack 4.0.1 but it didn't work and compilation terminated with this message `mltest.cpp:6:10: fatal error: mlpack/methods/kmeans.hpp: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <mlpack/methods/kmeans.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.` Nevertheless, I'm eagerly looking forward to the update you mentioned in the other SO thread.

Comment: Maybe double-check your local paths, and settings.  It "worked for me" with 4.0.1 installed.  But an improved `mlpack` package _with the headers_ should be on CRAN soon, hopefully in a mattter of days to maybe a few weeks.

Comment: I'm eagerly looking forward to the update!

Comment: Thanks again for the "poking". We overlooked this by accident and should have installed it in the upcoming form ever since 4.0 made this possible!

Comment: `mlpack` version 4.2.0 is now on CRAN